# open xml sdk excel formula recalculate cache issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have looked at all the previous answers to the similar questions in SO but those answers do not work. I pass in the value in excel and want the formula cell to recalculate but its still showing up the old value.

I have used the 2 techniques 1) remove the calculated value from the cell 2)Open and close the file programmatically. Both of them don't work for me. Here is my code. Please help.

```
            string filename = Server.MapPath("/") + "ExcelData.xlsx";



            // getting 2 numbers in excel sheet, saving, and closing it.

            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
            {
                Sheet sheet = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "myRange1");
                if (sheet == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        String.Format("No sheet named {0} found in spreadsheet {1}", "myRange1", filename), "sheetName");
                }
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);

                int rowIndex = int.Parse("C3".Substring(1));

                Row row = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().
                        Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);

                Cell cell3 = row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault(c => "C3".Equals(c.CellReference.Value));
                if (cell3 != null) 
                {
                    cell3.CellValue = new CellValue("13");
                    cell3.DataType = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number); 
                }

                document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts
   .SelectMany(part => part.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>())
   .SelectMany(data => data.Elements<Row>())
   .SelectMany(row1 => row1.Elements<Cell>())
   .Where(cell => cell.CellFormula != null && cell.CellValue != null)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(cell => cell.CellValue.Remove());

                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            }



            // getting the result out of excel.
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
            {
                document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
                document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;

                Sheet sheet = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "myRange1");
                if (sheet == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        String.Format("No sheet named {0} found in spreadsheet {1}", "myRange1", filename), "sheetName");
                }



                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);

                int rowIndex = int.Parse("C4".Substring(1));

                Row row = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().
                        Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);

                Cell cell = row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault(c => "C4".Equals(c.CellReference.Value));

                calculatedvalue = Convert.ToDouble(cell.CellValue.InnerText);
            }
```

Comment: Did you try the `ForceFullCalculation=true; ` in the first code-block just after the first time you open the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes.. I just tried it and it does not work. I have been posting the same question for last 3 days and still no one can not solve it.. Talk about frustration!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the by you provided code snippet I miss the essential part from the blog you referred to.

As stated in that blog OpenXML can only be used for creating/reading/updating and deleting the storage format for OpenXML compatible applications. You don't get the actual application engine. To achieve what you want you either need to install Excel on your server so you can leverage [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application)  and it's `Application` COM interface or rely on the end-users Excel application to do the recalculation when openening the updated excel sheet.

[code copied and text adapted from this blog](http://fczaja.blogspot.nl/2013/05/how-to-read-and-write-excel-cells-with.html)

```
var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFullPath(_filePath));
workbook.Close(true);
excelApp.Quit();
```

Please do realize that if you need this to run on a server (for example because you need the calculated results in a webpage) you might run into serious performance trouble, memory, I/O and CPU wise. In that case I would rather implement the calculation rules/formulas in C#.

Comment: Thanks rene, I did run into the blog that you mentioned but did not realize the importance of referencing excel and workbook as Microsoft.Interop... objects. I have tried it and it works like beautiful. Thank you so much for the help.. I very much appreciate it. It *** works ****

Comment: Hi Rene, what is the best way for this to work on windows azure web cloud application with out installing excel into the webserver? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see or know a way to accomplish that, see [also this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us). As I said, if you need the calculations serverside implement that in C#.

Comment: Thanks Rene.. I will take a look at that link. I posted a separate question on how to parse the formula.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336769/openxml-sdk-excel-how-to-parse-and-calculate-formula